# I can't paste a folder to a SD card

Tags: permissions

I inserted my SD card, I can copy from it but not to it. Looks like a permission problem, b ut everything I tried doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the size of what your trying to insert?

Answer (score 1):

Three most seen cases that one can not write to an SD card:

1. Your lock switch is in locked state, or your card reader have problem to think it's locked.  In this case, try your card on another reader.
2. OS detects file system error so it remounts SD card as R/O.  You can check by `mount` command. 
   For this case, put it in a Windows machine to do file system check, or you just re-format the card.
3. SD card is nearly broken, hardware ECC errors over threshold, so it locks itself to prevent further data damage.

   In this case, you can just replace it with a new card.

   Please note that on Windows it looks like that this kind of card can be written, but if you remove and insert again, every changes are not effective.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the SD Card isn't locked?

Another suggestion: try accessing nautilus as sudo (typing `sudo nautilus` on terminal) and try copying files to it. If it's a permission thing, may work.

Other suggestion: is this card formatted as exfat (like Canon camera's card?). Maybe you should install exfat-utils (`sudo apt install exfat-utils`), and then it will work.

Comment: Thanks, I did check, and it isn't locked. If I sudo nautilus, what are the commands to copy? It formatted as FAT32